# Iterating through elements of the same class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of div's belonging to the same class and
having form fields. I want to be able to iterate through the div's 
of the same class and get the hidden form elements and store in array.

i have created and array object that adds to an array after each iteration
but i think where i am getting it wrong is the iteration through the div's
Here is the structure

```
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="child_div" id="child_div_1" number="1">
        <div class="some_other_div">
        </div>
        <input id="name_1" type=hidden value="1.0"/>
        <input id="name_2" type=hidden value="4.0"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child_div" id="child_div_2" number="2">
        <div class="some_other_div">
        </div>
        <input id="name_2_1" type=hidden value="1.0"/>
        <input id="name_2_2" type=hidden value="4.0"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child_div" id="child_div_3" number="3">
        <div class="some_other_div">
        </div>
        <input id="name_3_1" type=hidden value="1.0"/>
        <input id="name_3_2" type=hidden value="4.0"/>
    </div>
</div>//end of parent div
```

I have written the jQuery code below to iterate through these div but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. So PLEASE HELP!

```
function doSomething() {
    var array = {};
    var rowCount = $("div .child_div").length;
    var rowNumber = 0;
    for (i=0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        //doing something...
        array[i] = arrayObj (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6);
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `var array = {};` is creating an object, not an array. Try `var array = [];` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var values = [];
$(".child_div").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input:hidden").each(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Also you might get all the inputs and map them:

```
var values = $('.child_div input:hidden').map(function (index, el) { return $(el).val(); }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `each()` method to do the looping.

```
var $items = $('.myClassName');

var myArray = new Array();


    $items.each(function(){
        var $hiddenItems = $(this).find('input:hidden');
        $hiddenItems.each(function(){myArray.push($(this))});
    });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wYkQs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of all hidden inputs that are within div's with the class "child_div", you can do this:

```
var array = $('.child_div input:hidden').get();
```

---

Edit: ... or, if you want to do more complex logic while creating your array, [$().map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) may be useful.  E.g.,

```
var values = $('.child_div input:hidden').map(function(i, el) {
    // return the value of each hidden input
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div .child_div').each(function(i){
   // do something
});
```